# findAll UUID MongoRepository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I'm trying to achive a findAllByUUID using mongo-spring-boot, but with no luck.
What I have:

```
public interface CarMatchRepository extends MongoRepository<CarMatchEntity, String> {
    List<CarMatchEntity> findAllByCarID(Iterable<UUID> ids);
    CarMatchEntity findByCarID(UUID carID);
}
```

Function call:

```
public void addCarsToCollection(String id, List<UUID> carId) {
   List<CarMatchEntity> entities = carMatchRepository.findAllByCarID(carId); <--- empty
}
```

If I call findByCarID() it retrieves correctly a single object (if exists) but using Iterable the query does not fail, but it never returns any object. Am I doing something wrong here or am I taking the wrong road for this problem?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

```
@Document(collection = "car_index")
public class CarMatchEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private UUID carID;

    //partner data
    private UUID partnerID;
    private String partnerThumbURL;
    private String partnerName;
    private Date partnerMembershipSince;

    // car location
    private List<Double> location;
    private String district;
    private String city;

    // car data
    private CarType carType;
    private String carBrand;
    private String carModel;
    private String carPlate;
    private List<CarFeature> carFeatures;

    private String carAddress;

    private String description;
    private BigDecimal hourFare;
    private BigDecimal dayFare;
    private BigDecimal weekFare;
    private BigDecimal dailyPrice;
    private BigDecimal suggestedHourlyPrice;
    private BigDecimal suggestedDailyPrice;
    private BigDecimal suggestedWeeklyPrice;
    private String carThumbURL;
    private Map<String, CarPhotos> carPhotosURL;
    private CarAvailability availability;
    private CarStatus carStatus;
    private String carYear;
    private FuelType fuelType;

    @Transient
    private DayOfWeek prohibitedDay;

    private String carYearModel;

    @Transient
    private double partnerRating = 5.0;
    private CarTransmission carTransmission;
    private CarColor carColor;
    private String odometer;
    private Integer manufactureYear;
    private String fipeCode;
    private String renavam;
    private String chassi;
    private InsuranceCompany insuranceCompany;
    private List<CarSpecialFeature> carSpecialFeatures;
    private BigDecimal deductible;
    private Boolean superCar;

    public CarMatchEntity() {

    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the fields of the `CarMatchEntity` ?

Comment: sure thing! done

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
List<CarMatchEntity> findAllByCarIDIn(Iterable<UUID> ids);
```

instead of

```
List<CarMatchEntity> findAllByCarID(Iterable<UUID> ids);
```

**UPDATE**:
Did you try to explicitly declare JPQL query instead of relying on Spring Data query generation mechanism?

```
@Query("select e from CarMatchEntity e where e.carID in (:ids)")
List<CarMatchEntity> findAllByCarID(@Param("ids") Iterable<UUID> ids);
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Another solution I would try is to declare argument `ids` in `findAllByCarIDIn` method as `Collection<UUID>` instead of `Iterable<UUID>`.

Comment: Hmm now I'm getting: `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
select e from CarMatchEntity e where e.carID in (:ids)`. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Am I supposed to use `import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;` ?

Comment: @Leonardo disregard my "Update 1", I messed Mongo and JPQL format. Correct format is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48013632/2224047

Answer (score 1):

Try using JSON based queries with SpEL expressions

```
@Query("{carID: { $in: ?0 } })")
List<CarMatchEntity> findAllByCarIds(List<UUID> ids);
```

Comment: Can you directly search for a UUID in your mongo collection?

Comment: @Leonardo what type is carID  in your MongoDB?

Comment: Yes, I can! I have the `CarMatchEntity findByCarID(UUID carID);` which returns the result.

Comment: Binary, Legacy UUID, or BinData(3, Base64). Thanks for the help